# Is there only one free (continuous) action of $\mathbb{Z}_2$ on $S^2$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, geometric-topology

We all know that the antipodal map is a free action of $\mathbb{Z}_2$ on $S^2$. Considering $\mathbb{Z}_2 = \{1, -1\}$, a free action may be viewed as a map $f : S^2 \rightarrow S^2$, i.e. the action of $-1$, with no fixed points, such that $f \circ f = Id_{S^2}$. We then readily see that $deg(f) = \pm 1$. Since $f$ does not have fixed points, it cannot have degree 1, and hence $f$ is homotopic to the antipodal map.

My question is: does this imply that the quotient of $S^2$ by this action is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{RP}^2$? Actually, I know this is true, because the quotient must be a closed surface with fundamental group $\mathbb{Z}_2$, so we can use the classification of closed surfaces. But I would like to be able to generalize this to spheres of any even dimension, so I wanted to see if I could get an answer that doesn't use that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, the result is not true in dimensions of the form $4k$.  That is, in each dimension of the form $4k$, there is a $Z_2$ action on $S^{4k}$ with quotient *not* homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}P^{4k}$.  (I don't know what happens in other dimensions.  I suspect that Ricci flow techniques in dimension $3$ would show that the the only $Z_2$ quotients of $S^3$ is the standard $\mathbb{R}P^3$.  I'm far from an expert in this area, though.)

More specifically, in

> D. Ruberman. Invariant Knots of free involutions of S4, Top. Appl. 18 (1984), 217-224

Ruberman shows that there is a non-smoothable $4$-manifold $X$ which is homotopy equivalent, but not homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}P^4$.

The universal cover $\tilde{X}$ of $X$ must therefore be homotopy equivalent to $S^4$.  By Freedman's classification, we know $\tilde{X}$ is homeomorphic to $S^4$.  Now, the deck group (which is isomorphic to $\pi_1(X)\cong \pi_1(\mathbb{R}P^2)\cong \mathbb{Z}_2$) acts freely on $\tilde{X}\cong S^4$.

Further, in

> R. Fintushel and R. J. Stern, Smooth free involutions on homotopy 4k-spheres, Michigan Math. J. 30 (1983), no.1, 37–51,

Fintushel and Stern find examples of smooth $4k$ manifolds (with $k>1$) which are homotopy equivalent, but not homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}P^{4k}$.  One can repeat the argument above (using Smale's proof of the Poincare conjecture in high dimensions instead of Freedman's result) to find the involutions on $S^{4k}$.

Comment: Is the quotient always homotopically equivalent to $\mathbb{RP}^2$ though?

Comment: For the $\mathbb{R}P^2$ case, you were exactly right:  The quotient of $S^2$ by a free action of $\mathbb{Z}_2$ is always homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}P^2$ (and your argument is the one I would have used).  I believe that, in general, the quotient $X$ of $S^n$ by a free $\mathbb{Z}_2$ action is always homotopy equivalent to $\mathbb{R}P^n$.  The proof I'm thinking of:  First, show $H^1(X;\mathbb{Z}_2) \cong \mathbb{Z}_2$.  Since $\mathbb{R}P^\infty$ is $K(\mathbb{Z}_2, 1)$, this gives a homotopically nontrivial map $X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}P^\infty$ which, by cellular approximation is...

Comment: homotopic to a map $X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}P^n$.  This map should be an isomoprhism on $\pi_1$, and all other homotopy groups vanish for trivial reasons.  Hence, Whitehead's theorem implies this map is a homotopy equivalence.

Comment: Jason: In dimension 3 this indeed follows from Perelman's theorem (although, I think, it was known earlier). By Perelman's theorem, every closed 3-manifold with finite fundamental group is homeomorphic to the quotient of $S^3$ by a finite subgroup of $O(4)$ acting freely. Now, the problem  of uniqueness reduces to simple linear algebra.

Comment: @studiosus:  I had some vague idea that Perelman's theorem implied that a closed $3$-manifold with finite fundamental group was a quotient of $S^3$, but I didn't realize one could assume the action of the deck group is conjugate to a subgroup of $O(4)$.  Granting that, I agree it's simple linear algebra from there.

Comment: Jason: One way to think about Perelman's theorem is as follows. There are some minimal homotopy-theoretic restrictions which closed manifolds of positive/negative curvature have to meet: For positive curvature, it is finiteness of $\pi_1$; for negative curvature, it is that the manifold is aspherical and its fundamental group contains no $Z^2$. Perelman's theorem says that in dimension 3 (as in dimension 2), these minimal requirements are also sufficient for existence of a metric of _constant_ positive/negative sectional curvature. (The rest of his theorem was known earlier.)

Comment: For my own reference, yes, the quotient of a homotopy sphere by a free involution is homotopy equivalent to real projective space.  An embarassingly simple proof is given by Hirsch and Milnor in Lemma 3 here: https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1964-70-03/S0002-9904-1964-11103-4/S0002-9904-1964-11103-4.pdf

Answer (score 2):

The quotients of such actions are called "Fake real projective spaces" and you find their classification in http://www.map.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/Fake_real_projective_spaces